# Beautiful soup : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'

Tags: python-3.x

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'

Beautiful soup package made the previous error in pycharm however i installed it using cmd and it was successfully installed.

Comment: Explain the problem clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try installing bs4 using `pip`

```
pip2 install bs4 # for Python2
pip3 install bs4 # for Python3
```

If you have both python2 and python3 installed in your system, You might have to create a virutal env and then install bs4